# How to print the type annotations of a function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So let's say I defined the following function with **type annotations**:

```
from typing import List
def my_function(input_1: str, input_2: int) -> List[int]:
    pass
```

Is there a way to show the annotated types of this function? Maybe a function `types_of` or something similar? So that it can be used like this:

```
>> types_of(my_function)
[str, int] -> [List[int]]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `__annotations__`

```
from typing import List
def my_function(input_1: str, input_2: int) -> List[int]:
    pass


In [2]: my_function.__annotations__
Out[2]: {'input_1': str, 'input_2': int, 'return': typing.List[int]}
```

Or you can use `get_type_hints` function from `typing` module. Actually I think this is more **appropriate solution**.

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) `get_type_hints` returns a dictionary containing type hints for a function, method, module or class object.

### Function example:

```
from typing import get_type_hints, List

def my_function(input_1: str, input_2: int) -> List[int]:
    pass

In [2]: get_type_hints(my_function)
Out[2]: {'input_1': str, 'input_2': int, 'return': typing.List[int]}
```

### Class example:

For a classes `get_type_hints` returns a dictionary constructed by merging all the `__annotations__` along `Foo.__mro__` in reverse order.

```py
class Bar:
    BAR_C: bool = True

class Foo(Bar):
    FOO_STR: str = 'foo'
    FOO_INT: int = 42

    def __init__(a: str, b: int) -> None:
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    def some_method(self, foo: List, bar: bool) -> bool:
        pass

In [7]: get_type_hints(Foo)
Out[7]: {'BAR_C': bool, 'FOO_STR': str, 'FOO_INT': int}

Out[8]: get_type_hints(Foo.__init__)
Out[8]: {'a': str, 'b': int, 'return': NoneType}

In [9]: get_type_hints(Foo.some_method)
Out[9]: {'foo': typing.List, 'bar': bool, 'return': bool}
```

### Module example

Our module `test_module.py`

```
from typing import Dict

SOME_CONSTANT: Dict[str, str] = {
    '1': 1,
    '2': 2
}


class A:
    b: str = 'b'
    c: int = 'c'


def main() -> None:
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then let's open python shell:

```
In [1]: from typing import get_type_hints
In [2]: import test_module

In [3]: get_type_hints(test_module)
Out[3]: {'SOME_CONSTANT': typing.Dict[str, str]}

In [4]: get_type_hints(test_module.A)
Out[4]: {'b': str, 'c': int}

In [5]: get_type_hints(test_module.main)
Out[5]: {'return': NoneType}
```

Comment: Plain and simple - nice! Does this also work for classes and decorators?

Comment: `get_type_hints` works for decorator functions too but it is actually returns only types from outer part.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `inspect` module:

```
import inspect
from typing import List

def my_function(input_1: str, input_2: int) -> List[int]:
    pass

def types_of(func):
    specs = inspect.getfullargspec(func)
    return_type = specs.annotations['return']
    input_types = [t.__name__ for s, t in specs.annotations.items() if s != 'return']
    return f'[{", ".join(input_types)}] -> {return_type}'

types_of(my_function)
```

output:

```
'[str, int] -> typing.List[int]'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#module-inspect)

```
import inspect

def sum_numbers(first_number=4,second_number=5):
    return a+b


def print_argtypes(function):
    specs = inspect.getfullargspec(sum_numbers)
    for s in range(len(specs[0])):
        print(specs[0][s]+': '+str(type(specs[3][s])))

print_argtypes(sum_numbers)
```

output

```
first_number: <class 'int'>
second_number: <class 'int'>
```